# Add DropDown in Sales Order Grid Section in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.2.5, order-grid

I have checked some of the links but they do not work my need so Please help someone who did this before

> sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="company_status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\CompanyStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CompanyStatus\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> Options.php

```
<?php

namespace Magento\CompanyStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CompanyStatus;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => 'Payment & Artwork: Y > Vplus',
            'value' => 0
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => 'Payment or Artwork: N',
            'value' => 1
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => 'Payment & Artwork: N',
            'value' => 2
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the dropdown in a column? Is it something like an action you want to perform?

Comment: I have to show the dropdown in the grid section. when the admin user changes the dropdown value so it will save in DB

Comment: I have a found a way for it. I am posting answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please change below code in your sales_order_grid.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="company_status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\CompanyStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CompanyStatus\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CompanyStatus/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> Now please create select.js file under path
> Magento/CompanyStatus/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/columns/

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select'
], function (_, Column) {
    'use strict';

    return Column.extend({
        defaults: {
            bodyTmpl: 'Magento_CompanyStatus/ui/grid/cells/select'
        }
    });
});
```

> Now please create select.html file under path
> Magento/CompanyStatus/view/adminhtml/web/template/ui/grid/cells/

```
<select>
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option value="0">Payment & Artwork: Y > Vplus</option>
    <option value="1">Payment or Artwork: N</option>
    <option value="2">Payment & Artwork: N</option>
</select>
```

After that you need to write ajax call on change of options. Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aPEMW2W

Comment: I tried with your code  but it does not display still if you have any solution so please help me on this

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know on this.

Comment: This code will insert dropdown field value. It will not show dropdown. According to your code in your question , it seems you wanted to show options value in column but you are not able to get it.

Comment: I have to show the dropdown in the grid section. so do you have ant idea?

Comment: Please check. I have updated code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below changes. You need to create column editor as below. On click of a row it will open editor for that row in the grid.

[image]

Magento/CompanyStatus/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="companystatus/order/inlineEdit"/>
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <column name="company_status" class="Magento\CompanyStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CompanyStatus">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\CompanyStatus\Model\Config\Source\CompanyStatuses</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Magento/CompanyStatus/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CompanyStatus.php

```
<?php

namespace Magento\CompanyStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\CompanyStatus\Model\Config\Source\CompanyStatuses as CompanyStatusOptions;

class CompanyStatus extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column {

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ){
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $companyStatuses = CompanyStatusOptions::getStatuses();
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item['company_status'] = $companyStatuses[$item['company_status']];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Magento/CompanyStatus/Model/Config/Source/CompanyStatuses.php

```
<?php

namespace Magento\CompanyStatus\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class CompanyStatuses implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    const STATUS_0 = 0;
    const STATUS_1 = 1;
    const STATUS_2 = 2;

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => 'Payment & Artwork: Y > Vplus',
            'value' => self::STATUS_0
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => 'Payment or Artwork: N',
            'value' => self::STATUS_1
        ];
        $options[] = [
            'label' => 'Payment & Artwork: N',
            'value' => self::STATUS_2
        ];
        return $options;
    }

    public static function getStatuses()
    {
        $options = [
            self::STATUS_0 => 'Payment & Artwork: Y > Vplus',
            self::STATUS_1 => 'Payment or Artwork: N',
            self::STATUS_2 => 'Payment & Artwork: N',
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Magento/CompanyStatus/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/InlineEdit.php

```
<?php

namespace Magento\CompanyStatus\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

class InlineEdit extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $jsonFactory;

    protected $orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $error = false;
        $messages = [];

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
            $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
            if (!count($postItems)) {
                $messages[] = __('Please correct the data sent.');
                $error = true;
            } else {
                foreach (array_keys($postItems) as $orderId) {
                        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
                    try {
                        $order->setData(array_merge($order->getData(), $postItems[$orderId]));
                        $this->orderRepository->save($order);
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $messages[] = "[ID: {$orderId}]  {$e->getMessage()}";
                        $error = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Magento/CompanyStatus/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="company_status" xsi:type="string">sales_order.company_status</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Magento/CompanyStatus/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="companystatus" id="companystatus">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Magento_CompanyStatus" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```